# Convert multidimensional list to multidimensional numpy.array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I am having trouble converting a python list-of-list-of-list to a 3 dimensional numpy array.

```
a = [
   [ 
     [1,2,3,4], # = len 4
     ...
   ], # = len 58
   ...
] # = len 1245
```

when I call `a = np.array(a)` on it, it reports shape as `(1245,)` and I cannot reshape it. `a.reshape(1245,58,4)` It gives me the error: 
`ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 1245 into shape (1245,58,4)` But If I print a[0] it gives me a 58 element list and a[0][0] gives me a 4 element list, as I expected, so the data is there.

I see plenty of stack exchange posts wanting to flatten it, but I just want to make it into a numpy array in the shape that it already is. I don't know why `numpy.array()` is not seeing the other dimensions.

Comment: Lists of the same level (the same numpy axis) need to be the same size. Otherwise you get an array of lists.

Comment: Good catch. I though they were, but your comment made me reevaluate that assumption. I while creating the lists, I was looping over the wrong variable - one that changed loop to loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lists of the same level (the same numpy axis) need to be the same size. Otherwise you get an array of lists.

```
np.array([[0, 1], [2]])[0]  # returns [0, 1]

np.array([[0, 1], [2, 3]])[0]  # returns array([1, 2])
```

You can get around this by calling [`pad`] on your lists before converting them to an array.

Furthermore the dimensions for [`reshape`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.reshape.html) "should be compatible with the original shape." Meaning (with the exception of a `-1` value for inference) the product of the new dimensions should equal the product of the old dimensions.

For example in your case you have an array of shape `(1245,)` so you could call:

```
a.reshape(83, 5, 3)  # works
a.reshape(83, -1, 3)  # works
a.reshape(83, 5, 5)  # fails since 83 * 5 * 5 = 2075 != 1245
```